# MS Operations Management Suite OPS

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm, oms

Before we use Microsoft OMS do we first need to setup and configure an MS Azure account?
I have tried to connect a server on step 2 but never can I get past that step.

Answer (score 0):

No you dont, unless you wish to change to a paid data plan. Keep in mind though, the free data plan is limited to 500Mb per day. Depending on your environment, it can quickly add up, say 2 hours of security events at which point it suspends data processing for the day.

Also, to address your second point . Adding a client is pretty simple. I assume you are following the steps showing below. Download the client, run it on the desired server, select **"Connect the agent to Microsoft Azure Operational Insight"** and then plug in the the ID/keys.

[image: MOMS Install]

Comment: Can I only use MS Server 2012 R2 to connect to the MS OMS console? I installed the agent on a MS Server 2008 Standard

Comment: Joe,OK, that's why I asked if I need an Azure account. It's just Microsoft's why of configuring a server. OK, I'll try that.

Comment: Joe, that worked agent installed on my 2008 server and now it's on to step 3. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: Joe, I'm also looking for a support/community to read. Is this a good one in your opion: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msoms/